# Unable to append HTML to an element in JavaScript or jQuery from inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use [Barba](http://barbajs.org/index.html) to implement smooth page transitions. Here is my code to append some HTML when a new page is added.

```
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(currentStatus, oldStatus, container) {  
  console.log("I am In.");
  $("#quick-share").append("Share Now!");
});
```

The appending works from the developer tools console but from inside this function it doesn't. However, the console.log() statement works properly without any issue. I have also tried a pure JavaScript way but it doesn't work inside the Barba function either.

```
document.getElementById("quick-share").innerHTML = "Share Now!";
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your "#quick-share" element is a generated tag or it already exist at the start of loading page ?

Comment: Are you sure that the element you're querying exists?

Comment: @Kashkain Yes, it already exists.

Comment: @SamHH Yes, that's why I could append the HTML from inside the developer console.

Comment: So if you directly drop that append code outside of the function it will work?

Comment: @SamHH Yes it works outside the function.

Comment: You are appending it inside an event handler `Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady'`, so it won't append this text onload, you have to fire this event, and honestly I don't know how will this `'newPageReady'` event fire?!

Comment: @chsdk I don't understand. According to the library the event is fired itself on page load. That's why all other code like the `console.log()` is working.

Comment: @chsdk Here is the link to the events. There are just four simple events so you can take a quick look at it. http://barbajs.org/events.html

Comment: So you are getting the output of `console.log("I am In.");`?

Comment: @chsdk Yes, I can get the output.

Comment: @NeenaVivek Can you try something like this : $(container).find("#quick-share").append("Share Now!")

Comment: @NeenaVivek Ok, I got it, may be the transition is overriding the the container content?

Comment: @chsdk, yes that is probably what's happening. Where should I add the code to append the HTML then? :)

Comment: @Kashkain `$(container).find("#quick-share").append("Share Now!")` did not work either.

Comment: @chsdk The documentation says that `newPageReady` is fired when "The new container has been loaded and injected in the wrapper.". Is it still possible that the HTML I added was overwritten?

Comment: @NeenaVivek If your tag is in the old container yes. See transitionCompleted completed event.

Comment: @Kashkain Yes, I am trying it now. :)

Comment: @Kashkain It worked. I can change the markup now.

Comment: Thanks @chsdk for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact with [**Barba.js**](http://barbajs.org/) when you make a transition, the new content will override the old one, that's what we can see in their [How it works section](http://barbajs.org/how-it-works.html):

> 5- As soon the new page is loaded, barba.js parses the new HTML (taking .barba-container) and puts the new content on the DOM inside #barba-wrapper.
>
> 6- The transition instance will take care of hiding the old container and
>   showing the new one.
>
> 7- As soon the transition is finished, the old container is removed from
>   the DOM.

So your problem is that when calling `$("#quick-share")`, in the `'newPageReady'`  event, the old content was removed so it won't return any element with that id, that's why you can't see the text appended.

What you can do is to recreate this element in the new container, in the `transitionCompleted` event handler.